# Continuous animation in android

Tags: android, animation

**How to translate the image in multiple direction in continuation on graphical coordinates**?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:duration="4000"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:toXDelta="500"
        android:toYDelta="500"/>

    <translate
        android:duration="4000"
        android:fromXDelta="500"
        android:fromYDelta="500"
        android:startOffset="4000"
        android:toXDelta="-1000"
        android:toYDelta="-250"/>

    <translate
        android:duration="4000"
        android:fromXDelta="-1000"
        android:fromYDelta="-250"
        android:startOffset="8000"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-250"/>

</set>
```

I want to translate the image like star. Please help me out in getting this animation.
I have posted my XML of animation which have translation defined

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

<!-- Use startOffset to give delay between animations -->


<!-- Move -->
<translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:startOffset="300"
    android:toXDelta="75%p" />
<translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:startOffset="1100"
    android:toYDelta="70%p" />
<translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:startOffset="1900"
    android:toXDelta="-75%p" />
<translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:startOffset="2700"
    android:toYDelta="-70%p" />

<!-- Rotate 360 degrees -->
<rotate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="3800"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="360" />

    </set>
```